# Google Natural Language API - Credentials

Tags: java, google-api

For authenticating to the Cloud Natural Language API I have set an environment variable pointing to the JSON File. Is there another way to do this or to authenticate to the API?

I call the API like this so far:

```
public boolean calculateTopics(UpdateWorker updateWorker, String language, List<String> api, List<String> corr, String savePath, boolean feedback) throws InvocationTargetException, IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, GateException {

        Map<String, Object> apis = startAPI(api, textList, language);

}

public Map<String, Object> startAPI(List<String> selectedAPI, List<String> text, String language) throws InvocationTargetException, IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, GateException {

    API apiExtract;

    apiExtract = new GoogleAPI(LanguageServiceClient.create());
    googleValues = apiExtract.getEntities(text, language);

}

    public Map<String, Object> getEntities(List<String> textArray, String language) {

            for(String textString : textArray) {
                analyze(textString, language);
                ent.addAll(entities);   
            }



      public List<Entity> analyze(String text, String textL) throws IOException {


              if (textL.equals("english")) {
                        textLanguage = "en";

                    } else {
                        textLanguage = "de";
                    }

              Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
                      .setLanguage(textLanguage).setContent(text).setType(Type.PLAIN_TEXT).build();
                AnalyzeEntitiesRequest request = AnalyzeEntitiesRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setDocument(doc)
                        .setEncodingType(EncodingType.UTF16).build();
                    AnalyzeEntitiesResponse response = entityAPI.analyzeEntities(request);

                    entities = response.getEntitiesList();
                    return entities;
          }
```

Comment: See there: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/auth

Comment: I have read this before, but maybe I just don't understand it or I can't make it work for my java code

Comment: Well, what's the code then? We can't keep discussing theories, I have given a link that talks about "there can be another way".

Comment: I edited my question with the code

Comment: There is nothing related to authentification in that code, so it uses Google's default credentials provider, whatever is configured. Read Javadoc for `LanguageServiceClient` and related classes, they discuss credentials as well.

Comment: "Is there another way to do this or to authenticate to the API?" Do you mean your current approach doesn't work, or that you don't like it for some reason? Please clarify. Additionally, if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just parts, it would really help.

Comment: Hope the code is enough. Depending on the GUI, what the user selects different APIs get called. I need my program as runnable jar. So far the credentials are set as an environment variable, this works. For the runnable jar, the environment variable is my problem.